# how to remove small notification icon in android studio apps

Tags: android, notifications

I'm building an android app which shows a notification when it's running. But the notification icon doesn't take the full size. Here is the code and an image of it.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder=new
NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ebyq.png)

when I set 'large icon', it takes the full size.

```
 .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)  
 .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZMEC.png)

What I wanted to do is, remove the small icon and only keep the large icon which shows as a bigger icon. But if I removed 'setLargeIcon(int)' and keep 'setLargeIcon(bigmap)', app doesn't show any notificaitons. So in order to get notifications I have to keep both icons. 
Could anyone give a solution for this. How can I keep only the large icon ?